# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when trying to access my firebase database

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

Using Node (Express) to access my firebase database. Every time I try to access I get an error like `1]    22222 segmentation fault (core dumped)  node server/app.js` I can't see what the problem is so I need some enlightenment:

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
var firebase = require("firebase-admin");
require("firebase/database")


const serviceAccount = require("./keys.json");

let config = {
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<MY_DB>.firebasedatabase.app",
};


firebase.initializeApp(config);

let db = firebase.database();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    db.ref().once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
    })
    res.send("Hello World!");
})

app.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log("Listened on port 5000!");
});
```

Comment: If you segfaulted Node that's impressive as that's a rare event. Is there a compiled extension you're using?

Comment: Follow-up questions: Which version of Node and dependencies, plus OS? We can try and reproduce this issue knowing more details.

Comment: @tadman I'm using Node v14.7.0, on Ubuntu 18.04.5. Firebase 8.2.4 and Express 4.17.1. Not sure what the question about a compiled extension is about so I cannot answer :)

Comment: What I mean is it's highly unusual for Node itself to segfault, but something like that in a compiled extension (as in has non-JavaScript code in it) can happen.

Comment: Does this happen on Node 15.6.0 which is the current release, or Node 14.15.4 which is the best LTS version? This may be a defect in Node which has been fixed with a patch.

Comment: @tadman I tried with Node 15.6.0 and now I get `4302 abort (core dumped)  node server/app.js`

Comment: Sounds like a deeper fault. If you can package up a minimal example which reproduces this issue, including a `package.json`, it may help the maintainer(s) fix the issue. I think you're on to something here, but I can't say for sure what. Nothing you're doing with the JavaScript here should cause a segmentation fault. At worst you'd get some kind of JavaScript runtime error.

Comment: What is `firebase/database`? Does running `node` on that cause the fault? It's not clear if it's this file in particular, or some other component which has the fault. Is there anything here you can comment out which removes the segfault?

Answer (score 2):

You need to downgrade to lesser than node 12. That's a bug  not fixed yet.Probably the link below is related https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1042